# VS 2017 reset font size within window

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How am I able to reset the font size on my find/replace window? I did try changing the font size within Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors to the defaults for the following options and it did not do anything.

- [All Text Tool Windows]
- Environment

[image]

Comment: Environment font settings sometimes don't take effect untill restarted.. Worth a try.

Comment: @demi That was the ticket - I don't know why I didn't think of that! Thank you - I'll accept your answer if you post an answer

Comment: Glad that helped. I'll copy paste the same comment, cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment font settings sometimes don't take effect untill restarted.. Worth a try.